# Get all style options for leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In order to customize the layers on my map by user input I want to list all possible style options, e.g. for a geoJSON-Layer. The possible options are [here in the API](http://mourner.github.io/Leaflet/reference.html#path-options).
I tried

```
console.log(L.Path.prototype.options);
```

and I only get a subset of the options in the API. The [associated source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Path.js) shows that some options are not set because they are inherited from other options, for example `fillColor`.

Of course I could copy the values from the API.. but I think there might be a better and more flexible way.